# How to make MMA distinguish between symbolic coefficients and variables when doing factorization?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, factorization

I what to factor a polynomial with complicated symbolic coefficients

```
Factor[p0^2 + k^2 r^2 \[Tau]^2 - 2 k p0 r \[Tau]^2 \[Omega] + p0^2 \[Tau]^2 \[Omega]^2]
```

In which variable is only \[Omega]. But this will just out put the original polynomial without any change. Should I add something or use another function?

Comment: In the Reals, this polynomial is irreducible.  Try calculating the roots.

Comment: @DanielHuber I knew that, but I just what to factor in complex filed.

Comment: *I just what to factor in complex filed.* This is important information that belongs in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I just what to factor in complex filed

```
p = p0^2 + k^2 r^2 τ^2 - 2 k p0 r τ^2 x + p0^2 τ^2 x^2
Factor[p, Extension -> I]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]